# Modeling editable lists in DTOs used by services

Tags: rest, servicestack

Say you have the following Contact DTO. Address/PhoneNumber/EmailAddress/WebSiteAddress classes are simple DTOs as well (just data no behavior)

```
public class Contact
{
    public Address[] Addresses { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public EmailAddress[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public WebSiteAddress[] WebSiteAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

How should I model DTOs to allow implementing the following behavior?

The client can submit a request that will

- add a phone number, update two phone numbers and delete two add two
- add two email addresses, update one email address and delete three
- add three website addresses, update two website addresses and delete
  two. You get the idea.

  One option is to add an Action attribute to each Address / PhoneNumber / EmailAddress / WebSiteAddress.

Then the code the update addresses look like this:

```
        var addressesToUpdate = serviceContact.Addresses.Where(x =>  x.AddressAction.ToUpper() == "UPDATE");
        var addressesToAdd = serviceContact.Addresses.Where(x => x.AddressAction.ToUpper() == "ADD");
        var addressesToDelete = serviceContact.Addresses.Where(x => x.AddressAction.ToUpper() == "DELETE").Select(x => x.AddressId);
```

Repeating this for all other lists will probably create duplication.

My question is:

How should I model service DTOs with updatable lists while avoiding duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I'll try to keep my writes [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) which means it should have the same side-effect (i.e. end result) of calling it when you have no records or all records (i.e. Store or Update).

Basically this means that the client sends the **complete state**: i.e.

- What entries don't exist => gets created,
- The entities that already exist => get updated,
- Whilst the entities that aren't in the request DTO => get deleted.

[OrmLite's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) `db.Save()` command has nice support for this where it detects if a record(s) already exist and will issue an UPDATE otherwise will INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)s with conditional requests instead of providing the complete state. Use the ETag as a version of the list and change it each time the list changes. On the client side, use the ETag to request an update using the If-None-Match http header and be prepared to receive a 402 Precondition Failed status if the list changed while the request was sent.

Comment: No samples, but I use something like this in my OnPost when the Etag changed: `return new HttpResult
        {
          StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed,
          StatusDescription = "Precondition Failed",
        };` and I use this on the client side to catch the condition: `catch (WebServiceException e)
      {
        if (e.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed) ... }`