# Adding caching support to service step by step

Tags: servicestack

I want to use memory caching in my service but not able to configure it. I already registered it in `global.asax` as per instructions.

Here is how my service looks:

```cs
public class CustomerSerivce: Service
{
    public CustomerResponse Any(Customer customer)
    {
        //code to connect to db here - this code is called regardless of cache entry
        return customer;
    }
}
```

I know there is `this.RequestContext.ToOptimized` or something is there but some how it is not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the step by step is [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). You can also look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283839/modeling-editable-lists-in-dtos-used-by-services/12300042#12300042) for the missing link with http 304 Not Modified handling.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have declare:
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;

for extension methods of

```
base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(...)
```

?