# How to improve response time

Tags: servicestack

I am using latest version of ServiceStack. I am using in memory cache provided by service stack since my service is reading data from slow database.

After implementation of all of this, service response time is from 5-7 seconds which is too slow. Is it possible to get it optimized and make it more responsive.

Here is my code in concept:

```cs
public class CustomerService : Service
{
    public object Any(Customer request)
    {
        string cacheKey = "customerReport_" + request.Id;
        report = CacheClient.Get<BalanceReport>(cacheKey);
        if(report != null)
            return report;

        //Logic to build report.
        //I am caching the report object here before returning report.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http caching to help your requests. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283839/modeling-editable-lists-in-dtos-used-by-services/12300042#12300042) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the Caching pattern that's built into ServiceStack, e.g:

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
        public object Any(Customer request)
        {
            string cacheKey = "customerReport_" + request.Id;
            return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
                this.CacheClient, cacheKey, () => {
                    //Logic to build report.
                    //I am caching the report object here before returning report.
                    return repo.GetCustomerReport(request.Id);
                });
        }
}
```

You can read more about [ServiceStack Caching on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). Basically it stores the most optimal web service response in the cache, e.g. Deflate/Compressed JSON bytes (if it was a JSON request).